# Excel Group IF Statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, group

```
STUDENT SCORE
1   PASS
1   MOD1
1   MOD2
2   MOD1
3   MOD2
3   MOD2
3   MOD1
3   ER
4   MOD2
4   ER
```

I have this data above and wish to collapse into this data below

```
STUDENT SCORE
1   PASS
2   MOD1
3   PASS
4   MOD2
```

The rule is:

```
For each STUDENT
    if any value of SCORE equals to PASS, then is PASS
if contains value MOD1 and MOD2, then is PASS
if contains value MOD1, then is MOD1
if contains value MOD2, then is MOD2
```

it may contain random things like ER which is to be ignored.Simply check all values for each STUDENT and make a simpled table like shown

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/using-if-with-and-or-and-not-functions-d895f58c-b36c-419e-b1f2-5c193a236d97

Comment: this may look ugly, and you can tweak it for further use cases, but a simple formula is this: =IF(OR(COUNTIFS(A1:A10;E1;B1:B10;"PASS")>0;AND(COUNTIFS(A1:A10;E1;B1:B10;"MOD1")>0;COUNTIFS(A1:A10;E1;B1:B10;"MOD2")>0));"PASS";IF(AND(COUNTIFS(A1:A10;E1;B1:B10;"MOD1")>0;COUNTIFS(A1:A10;E1;B1:B10;"MOD2")=0);"MOD1";IF(AND(COUNTIFS(A1:A10;E1;B1:B10;"MOD1")=0;COUNTIFS(A1:A10;E1;B1:B10;"MOD2")>0);"MOD2")))

Comment: Where your first data is stored in the A and B columns, and the students numbers are stored in the E column. Then, in the F column, you use this formula to apply the above algorithm.

Comment: @CHill60 i know how to use those functions but not how to do it by groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To spill result at once:

```
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(A1:A10),MAP(UNIQUE(A1:A10),LAMBDA(z,LET(a,FILTER(B1:B10,A1:A10=z),IF(SUM(N(a="PASS"))>0,"PASS",IF(AND(SUM(N(a="MOD1"))>0,SUM(N(a="MOD2"))>0),"PASS",IF(SUM(N(a="MOD1"))>0,"MOD1",IF(SUM(N(a="MOD2"))>0,"MOD2","Not found"))))))))
```

[image]